# How to connect to password protected Wifi AP from android console?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, wifi-configuration

I have Internet for my PC from ISP which provides Internet access through fiber optics.

The network connection is stable most of the time however it happens that my ISP sometimes has a few problems and the network works slower or not at all for several hours.

I have a tablet with Internet access through my carrier, and I want to know how to use it as backup for my PC when my ISP drops. The tablet is rooted, and has busybox and terminal emulator installed.

What I want to do is be able to connect to the fiber optic router (shared from ISP and I can't access it) WiFi AP without changing the default route to the Internet through the mobile network on tablet (when I normally connect to my wireless AP then it tries to access Internet through that network).

That way I could add a default route on my PC through the tablet's LAN IP. On the tablet in the console, 'iwconfig', 'iwlist', and 'ifconfig' seems to work and I also did try wpa_supplicant but had no luck while trying to connect to AP.

Comment: when I normally connect to AP then wlan0 is up and has LAN IP but carrier (rmnet0) is down. When I do 'ifconfig rmnet0 up' then becomes up bat has no IP

Comment: I tryied 'iwconfig wlan0 essid <essid> key s:<password>' but I got reply 'Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A)'